# Creating ionic 1.x app with ionic 2 CLI

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I downloaded ionic 2 andI am able to create apps with it just fine.
I do that by following command

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics1 --v2
```

However I still want to create 1.x apps. How can I do that without removing ionic globally and making global changes?

Something like

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics1 --v1
```

installs ionic 1.x.

I do not want to go through removing entire ionic module globally then start all over again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now Ionic Updated the Docs.

If we want to create older version of Ionic App, Declare the Version Number while creating the App.

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics --type ionic1
```

Create latest Version (i.e - V2 or Higher) of Ionic App.

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics
```

Comment: It's still build a V2 app

Comment: @Gino are you trying to say `ionic start cutePuppyPics --V1` still creates  V2 App?

Comment: Please see Prijesh Meppayil or Gururaj Bhandarkar's answers. 

`ionic start cutePuppyPics1 --type=ionic1`

Answer (score 6):

Now these are deprecated and if you want to get v1 app using cli 2 
have to use

```
ionic start myApp --type ionic1
```

However using

`ionic start myApp`

will return latest version of ionic

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below command:

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics1 --type=ionic1
```

Reference : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that you can run V1 within V2. Just use "ionic start cutePuppyPics1" for V1 project and "ionic start cutePuppyPics2 --V2" for V2 project.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 0):

> If you not specify --v2 it creates for v1.x

```
e.g ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

above command create v1.x project

Answer (score -3):

You can try:

```
ionic start myApp --type=ionic1
```

Reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/